# How to exclude routes from route GET

Tags: laravel, vue.js

New to laravel so Im trying to do something that doesn't work. I'm building a backend dashboard with login & register page, these 2 pages should have different layouts. How can I do this as the way below is not working. I'm using VUE.

Of course is {any} gonna get all so is there a way to exclude pages from this?

web.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
   return view('layouts.vue');
})->where('any', '.*');

Route::get('/login', function () {
   return view('entry.vue');
})->name('login');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add your route on top of route with `{any}`.

For example:

```
Route::get('/somewhere', function () {
   return view('somewhere');
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
   return view('entry.vue');
})->name('login');

Route::get('/{any}', function () {
   return view('layouts.vue');
})->where('any', '.*');
```